# Search for multiple string occurrence in String via PHP

Tags: regex, model-view-controller, preg-match-all, substr

I am working on an ecommerce website using MVC,php. I have a field called description. The user can enter multiple product id's in the description field.

For example `{productID = 34}, {productID = 58}`

I am trying to get all product ID's from this field. Just the product ID.

How do i go about this?

Comment: You need a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract desired matches: [`/productID = (\d+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/aGs2VQ/1) (`\d` matches a digit `[0-9]`). See [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/686248)

Comment: @bobblebubble For several reasons that I don't wish to type out on my phone, please practice good SO citizenship and resist the urge to post answers as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't use a capture group.  Rather, it uses `\K` so that the full string elements become what would otherwise be captured using parentheses.  This is a good practice because it reduces the array element count by 50%.

```
$description="{productID = 34}, {productID = 58}";
if(preg_match_all('/productID = \K\d+/',$description,$ids)){
  var_export($ids[0]);
}

// output: array(0=>'34',1=>'58')

// \K in the regex means: keep text from this point
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Without using regex, something like this should work for returning the string positions:

<code>
    $html = "dddasdfdddasdffff";
    $needle = "asdf";
    $lastPos = 0;
    $positions = array();

    while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
        $positions[] = $lastPos;
        $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
    }

    // Displays 3 and 10
    foreach ($positions as $value) {
        echo $value ."<br />";
    }
</code>
```

Comment: Awesome Arun. Great answer. But what i want is to search for the specific string called product ID. this string product ID can be repeated multiple times in the description field. and for each instance, the ID is different. How do i do this? Thanks bro

Comment: Down voted because this answer ignores the OP's input string -- this makes the entire answer less helpful.  Please edit or delete this answer.